Got trouble during on building Mediapipe Example "hand_tracking_cpu"
I'm doing project with Mediapipe, and i successed install and built "hello_wolrd". But, I got trouble during on building "hand_tracking_cpu" like this:
참고: 포함 파일:  external/org_tensorflow\tensorflow/lite/util.h
참고: 포함 파일: external/org_tensorflow\tensorflow/lite/kernels/kernel_util.h
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(361): error C4430: 형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(361): error C2143: 구문 오류: ','이(가) '*' 앞에 없습니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(368): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(368): error C2065: 'rank': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(369): error C2065: 'output_shape': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(369): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(370): error C2065: 'output': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(370): error C2065: 'init': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(371): error C2065: 'Op': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(371): error C2065: 'input': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(371): error C2065: 'window_shape': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(371): error C2065: 'window_reduce_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(372): error C2065: 'output': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(372): error C2065: 'rank': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(373): error C2065: 'input': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(373): error C2065: 'window_offset_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(373): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(374): error C2065: 'output': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(374): error C2065: 'output_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(374): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(377): error C2065: 'output_shape': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(377): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(378): error C2065: 'Op': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(378): error C2065: 'input': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(378): error C2065: 'output': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(378): error C2065: 'output_shape': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(378): error C2065: 'output_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(379): error C2065: 'window_offset_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(379): error C2065: 'window_shape': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(380): error C2065: 'window_reduce_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(380): error C2065: 'init': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(380): error C2065: 'rank': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(380): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(381): error C2065: 'input': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(381): error C2065: 'window_offset_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(381): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(382): error C2065: 'output': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(382): error C2065: 'output_strides': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/stablehlo_reduce_window.cc(382): error C2065: 'depth': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.
Target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.496s, Critical Path: 2.46s
INFO: 53 processes: 23 internal, 30 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

so, Is there anybody conflicting same problem with me? or Is there anybody successed to shoot this trouble? The code I'd run is this:
bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu --verbose_failures


I encountered the same problem and fixed it by editing the file stablehlo_reduce_window.cc located at C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\_bazel_<USER_NAME>\<HASH_OF_OUTPUT_BASE>\external\org_tensorflow\tensorflow\lite\kernels\.
The problem seems to be the comment before the function ReduceWindowImpl.
Simply adding a new line before the function will fix it.
// Recursively computes strided reductions using a sliding window over the
// given tensor.
//
// The window is defined using a shape and a dilation. The shape defines the
// elements that the window will let the reduction *see*. The dilation defines
// the step between window elements.
//
// For instance: the following window has a [2, 2] shape and [2, 3] dilations.
//
//    3
// ┌────┐
// ┌─┐   ┌─┐
// │X│X X│X│┐
// └─┘   └─┘│2
//  X X X X ┘
// ┌─┐   ┌─┐
// │X│X X│X│
// └─┘   └─┘
// <= Add new line HERE
template <class Op, class Type>
void ReduceWindowImpl(const Type* input, Type* output,

I don't know why the comment would cause compilation issue (maybe due to the non-ASCII character?), but at least this solves the problem.
